# R changing a variable name for each data set within a list

Tags: r, list, names

I have a list of dataframes `sub_lst`. Within each dataframe I want to change the name of the variable in column 1. The varaible name is different in all the dataframes so I'm assuming I need to use indexing.

I have written the following function:

```
col1name <- function(x, na.rm=TRUE){names(x)[1] = "Time" }
```

Which I then pass to `lapply`:

```
sub_lst_new <- lapply(sub_lst, col1name)
```

However, this just replaces the dataframe with [1] "Time"

Can someone help me out - I'm sure there is a very simple solution but I've been banging my head against the desk all morning!

Comment: We need to return the `x` in the `col1name` function

Comment: Great, could you ellaborate on how to do that please? Thanks

Comment: I changed the function to: col1name <- function(x, na.rm=TRUE){names(x)[1] = "Time"; return(x) } `

Comment: This didn't work as the out put is now `[[1]] Time "Gyffin"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work

```
sub_list <- lapply(sub_list, function(x) {names(x)[1L] <- 'Time'; x})
sapply(sub_list, names)[1,]
#[1] "Time" "Time" "Time"
```

#### data

```
set.seed(24)
sub_list <- lapply(1:3, function(i)
  as.data.frame(matrix(sample(0:9, 4*5, replace=TRUE), ncol=4)))
```

Comment: Brilliant - that works a treat. It surprises me taht it is (relatively complex. It was easy to changes variable name when the name was the same for all dataframes with in the list - I used `renamenewvars<- function(x, na.rm=TRUE){rename(x,c( "X72.hours" = "Mean_1"...`

Comment: @RoryShaw I guess `rename` is from `plyr`.   For changing column names, either `names` (in data.frame) or `colnames` should work in both data.frames and matrices.

Comment: Yes `rename` is from `Plyr`. I'm going to try and wrap up your code into a nice function now